# How to get all parent note of particular category-id from given sql table?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my **category** table.....

[image]

I want a single query that shows all above parents of particular category_id. example: If in query i define category_id=7 then result will be like that:

7 PORTABLE ELECTRONICS 6

6 ELECTRONICS 1

and parent of 1 is null then query will terminate. In short, I just want all parents of particular category_id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you like the output to look?

Comment: I want a single query that shows all above parents of particular category_id. example: If in query i define category_id=7 then result will be like that: 7 PORTABLE ELECTRONICS 6.....6 ELECTRONICS 1...and parent of 1 is null then query will terminate. In short, I just want all parents of particular category_id.

Comment: Have a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set @category := 7
;

select      l.n
           ,elt(l.n,c1.category_id,c2.category_id,c3.category_id,c4.category_id,c5.category_id,c6.category_id,c7.category_id,c8.category_id,c9.category_id)     as category_id
           ,elt(l.n,c1.name,c2.name,c3.name,c4.name,c5.name,c6.name,c7.name,c8.name,c9.name)                                                                    as parent_name

from                    category    as c1
            left join   category    as c2   on c2.category_id = c1.parent
            left join   category    as c3   on c3.category_id = c2.parent
            left join   category    as c4   on c4.category_id = c3.parent
            left join   category    as c5   on c5.category_id = c4.parent
            left join   category    as c6   on c6.category_id = c5.parent
            left join   category    as c7   on c7.category_id = c6.parent
            left join   category    as c8   on c8.category_id = c7.parent
            left join   category    as c9   on c9.category_id = c8.parent

            cross join (            select 1    as n
                        union all   select 2 
                        union all   select 3 
                        union all   select 4 
                        union all   select 5 
                        union all   select 6 
                        union all   select 7 
                        union all   select 8 
                        union all   select 9
                        ) l

where       c1.category_id = @category  

        and l.n <= 
            case 
                when c9.category_id is not null then 9
                when c8.category_id is not null then 8
                when c7.category_id is not null then 7
                when c6.category_id is not null then 6
                when c5.category_id is not null then 5
                when c4.category_id is not null then 4
                when c3.category_id is not null then 3
                when c2.category_id is not null then 2
                when c1.category_id is not null then 1
            end
;
```

Comment: it gives only single parent, means if I enter 7, it gives 7's parent is 6 but  I want all parents, like 7's parent is 6 and 6's parent is 1.

Comment: No, it gives all parents. Please execute the inner query and verify. You should get 1,2,6 and 7

Comment: if user enters 7 then it should display the immediate parent of 7 and above all.

Comment: In MySQL it's going to be very ugly and you have to determine the maximum depth in advance. Please define the desired output, rows and colmns.

Comment: I want a single query that shows all above parents of particular category_id. example: If in query i define category_id=7 then result will be like that: 7 PORTABLE ELECTRONICS 6.....6  ELECTRONICS  1...and parent of 1 is null then query will terminate. In short, I just want all parents of particular category_id.